# Unable to put spaces in variable names - Visual Studio 2015 (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, spaces

I'm doing some very basic coding for making a receipt in Visual Studio 2015 in C++. I'm having trouble creating names with spaces without being forced to use underscores (ex. Item 1 vs Item_1). I feel like it's a simple fix, but I'm extremely new to coding as a whole.

Or if anything just have the output (receipt) show Item 1 and not Item_1.

This is my current code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double Item_1;
    double Item_2;
    double Item_3;
    double Total;

    Item_1 = 2.50;
    Item_2 = 0.75;
    Item_3 = 12.98;
    Total = Item_1 + Item_2 + Item_3;

    cout << "Thank you for shopping at StuffMart" << endl;
    cout << "Item_1 = " << Item_1 << endl; 
    cout << "Item_2 = " << Item_2 << endl;
    cout << "Item_3 = " << Item_3 << endl;
    cout << "Total = " << Total << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You found the fix. You could do camelCasing as well.

Comment: There are rules for identifiers in c++: http://www.c4learn.com/cplusplus/cpp-variable-naming/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the CPP [language reference documenation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers):

> An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of digits, underscores,
>   lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and most Unicode characters
>   (see below for details). A valid identifier must begin with a
>   non-digit character (Latin letter, underscore, or Unicode non-digit
>   character). Identifiers are case-sensitive (lowercase and uppercase
>   letters are distinct), and every character is significant.

In summary, an identifier (ie. variable name, function name, class name, etc.) cannot have a space in it. Spaces are used to help delimit tokens that make up the language.

Comment: For the output the show "Item 1" would I just completely avoid trying to use Item 1 as a variable, or how would I go about getting the output to return "Item 1" or  "Mens Shirt", etc? Currently, having a variable for the name isn't necessary for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: `\w+` matches `123`, which isn't an identifier.

Comment: @KemyLand Was removing that as you were typing this comment. Additional clarification would be confusing, so the point has been removed.

Comment: @ChristopherTerry: You can replace `cout << "Item_1 = " << Item_1` with `cout << "Item 1 = " << Item_1" and it'ld still compile. Strings (such as `"Item 1") are completely unrelated to variables.

Comment: @ChristopherTerry Variables names are used to reference data in programs. Strings are used to communicate text. The only relation between to two are how you as the programmer put them together. It is valid to say `cout << "Item 1" << Item_1`, where the string is in double quotes and the variable is `Item_1`.

Answer (score 2):

You Cant Have Spaces In Between Variable Name.

```
example: 

int shan kar;//Wrong Declaration
int int;//Wrong Declaration You Cant Have Keywords in place of variables


int shankar;//Valid Declaration
int shan_kar;//Valid Declaration
```

Rules To Declare CPP Variables:
http://www.sitesbay.com/cpp/cpp-variable-declaration

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you can't. In most languages (and this includes C++), the rules for naming identifiers (such as variable names) are as follows:

- The name should consist of at least 1 character.
- The first character shall be either an underscore (`_`), an uppercase latin letter (`A` through `Z`), or lowercase latin letter (`a` through `z`).
- All subsequent characters may consist of the same characters allowed for the first character, plus the decimal digits (`0` through `9`).

As such, we can conclude, **spaces are, by no means, allowed in identifiers*.

(Additionally, most languages lack support for names with symbols other than `A` through `Z`, `a` through `z`, `0` through `9` and the underscore (`_`). The exceptions are few, and, for the matter being, are not worth worrying about.)

For instance, the following are valid names in C++:

- `foo`
- `foo_bar`
- `MyVariable123`

And the following are not:

- `123variable`
- `my integer`
- `français`

You should also take into account that you shouldn't use the following identifiers, since they're reserved:

- Identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (such as `_Z3var`).
- Identifiers containing any two adjacent underscores (such as `__baz` or `some__identifier`).
- Keywords (such as `int`, `long`, `if`, `for`, etc...) are special identifiers which the language reserves for special purposes.